# Dismissing animation of the "Sign in with apple" modal view is broken on iOS 15.1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple

When closing the "Sign in with apple" modal view on a real device on iOS15.1, the modal view jumps to the center of the screen then animate to the bottom and disappears. But the dismissal animation is correct on the simulator.
I tested other apps with "Sign in with apple", they have the same issue.

How can I fix the animation?

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn,
                              onRequest: signInWithAppleOnRequest,
                              onCompletion: signInWithAppleOnComplete
        )
      }
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all)

    }
  
  // MARK: Sign in with Apple on request

  func signInWithAppleOnRequest(request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
  }
  
  // MARK: Sign in with Apple on complete

  func signInWithAppleOnComplete(result: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) {
  }
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having a similar behavior I don't know if it's a bug or not.

Comment: Glad to know someone has already flagged this. Cheers

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?

Comment: Relatedly, is there a way to listen for the `cancel` event if the modal was triggered by a website?

Comment: The bug was fixed in iOS 15.4.1

Comment: [Cheers Yi-Hsiu Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311192/yi-hsiu-lee), I needed to implement an Apple Sign in recently vaguely remembered discussing it on Stack Overflow.